# How to add a run button in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

i am a newcomer to this site and i'm not english so excuse me if this post isn't as good as you expected. Let's get to the point: to give you an example of what i mean with "run button", take the python one for example.

Once you install python extension in visual studio code, you can press a button in the right top of the screen, and then vsc automatically executes a command in a shell running python on the active .py file.

Given this example, I'd like to know how to make a button for vsc that automatically creates a new terminal, executes a command which i would insert in the making of the button and nothing else, of course the terminal shall not disappear after giving the desired output.

Just to give you some more info, i'm on ubuntu, if that helps anyhow.
Feel free to tell me whether i should edit this question in anyway.

Comment: read on the doc pages of VSC how to use it for different languages, go to the Run/Debug bar, there you find the defined launch configurations, if you are a beginner programmer you might first look at IDE's for you language of choice, VSC is an editor with benefits.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks!

Comment: Try Code Runner by publisher:"Jun Han"
Run C, C++, Java, JS, PHP, Python, Perl, Ruby, Go, Lua, Groovy, PowerShell, CMD, BASH, F#, C#, VBScript, TypeScript, CoffeeScrip...
It will add one Play/Run icon in Right Top of your code editor source file, I hope this is what you required.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Install the [Task Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SanaAjani.taskrunnercode) extension. Now, every task you add to `tasks.json` will be displayed as a button, in the 'Task runner' panel (which is normally on the same tab as the file explorer).

Here's a decent `tasks.json` template:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "COMMAND NAME",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "YOUR COMMAND HERE",
            "presentation": {"echo": true, "reveal": "always", "focus": false, "panel": "shared", "showReuseMessage": false, "clear": true},
        },
        // More tasks here, if you need them.
    ]
}
```

Put this file in your project directory, in a directory called `.vscode`. Open the project directory with "File" -> "Open Folder".

Comment: Thank you a lot! That worked. Since i'm new to this site i wonder if i have to tag this question as answered or something like that? Or does it get closed on its own after a while?

Comment: @Luxo You're welcome! The question gets marked as solved if you press the checkmark next to one of the answers.

Comment: Is it possible to use this button in an extension, without downloading the task runner?

Comment: @xtay2 What do you mean by "in an extension"?

Comment: I have written a language interpreter, a vscode syntaxhighlighter and vscode language support, and now want to use the run-code button to execute my interpreter for the current opened language file.

Comment: @xtay2 Are you writing a custom extension to be able to run the interpreter? If yes, then there are probably better ways to run commands than using tasks.

Comment: Exactly! But I havent come across any of them...

Comment: I prefer to keep the config on a single line, this way long lists of tasks are easier to read.

Answer (score 7):

Install Code Runner extension in VS Code

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I know you did not ask for debugging, but you can use the debugger launch mechanism on arbitrary programs. You can define `launch.json` to implement any number of launch configurations. The currently selected configuration will display a button you can click on.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Answer (score 2):

Add Code Runner Extension and you will see a RUN BUTTON on the Top Right in VS code. Like this
[image]

Comment: isn't this standard behavior now even without code runner, or does code runner add functionality?

Answer (score -1):

you can add the Code Runner extension.
This will show a run button on top of the editor panel