# Adding the run-code option to a new language in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, yeoman-generator

I'm currently writing my own language and I'm at a point where I would like to publish it to the VSCode-Marketplace so people can test it.

I have written a language extension and a syntax highlighter with the Yeoman-Generator and now want to merge it with my executable file that launches the interpreter, so that a file can get interpreted after clicking the run-code button.

[image: Code Image]

I now have checked multiple articles, like:

- How to add a run button in visual studio code? - [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66958884/how-to-add-a-run-button-in-visual-studio-code/66959200)
- How to define or support a code language on Visual Studio? - [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47913048/how-to-define-or-support-a-code-language-on-visual-studio)
- Debugger Extension Guide - [VSCode API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/debugger-extension)

However, I haven't found anything useful.

Currently, the code-runner displays the following error, when clicking on run, or pressing the shortcut:
[image]

> (Code language not supported or defined.)

But even after a lot of browsing Google for adding new language support to the code-runner, I found absolutely nothing helpful.

(See [this](https://coderunnerapp.com/support) page, idk what Settings/Preferences they are referring to!?)

I also was not successful with tasks, as they don't seem to connect to the run-buttom or debug-button in any way.

My question is: How can I make the run-button execute a custom bash-command, when a file in my language is opened?

Comment: don't use the code-runner extension, add you own run button with a `when` clause of you languageID, let the button type the required command in the terminal

Comment: Could you be a little more specific, please? Where should I put that?

Comment: look where you can add buttons to menu's (contribution point), the editor top-right is one of the locations, add an icon to the command and put it in the first group of the specific menu.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I finally did it.

For anyone wondering:

1. You have to go to the settings and type "code-runner" into the search bar.
2. Scroll down a little, and you should find the code runner-executor map.
   [image]
3. Click on the "edit in settings.json" button.
4. Now a .json-file should've opened. There are two possible scenarios: Either, there is a json-object called `code-runner.executorMapBy...` or not.
5. If there is none, type `code-runner.executorMapByFileExtension` and let autocomplete do the job.
6. If the json-object exists, add the file-extension and a bash command that executes your compiler/interpreter. It gets automatically executed in the directory the program-file lies in.

Now still dont know, how to include the settings in my extension, but that was already a big step. Further help is still appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source extension called [code runner](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner), you can check source code there.