# Setup make build tasks with externally created makefiles in Visual Studio Code with C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, makefile, compiler-errors

(Note: this OP is a properly split part of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77282899/disable-code-analysis-in-visual-studio-code-with-c), after [this correct comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77282899/disable-code-analysis-in-visual-studio-code-with-c#comment136442440_77282899). The original question was suitably adapted. All this improves SO.)

I am slowly migrating from Eclipse CDT to VSCode with C/C++ Extension Pack.
I am working under Ubuntu 22, with g++.

I have a large C++ package, with its own CMake files.
Note that, when working at the command prompt, I use CMake to generate `makefile`s, and then compiling/linking with `make <flags> <target>`.
I don't use `cmake --build`, e.g. (This is simply an "inherited" procedure in a large project, and I never bothered changing that. If I were to start from scratch I would probably do so, and I might in the future).

When working in Eclipse, I am used to setting up make targets so I compile/link with a double click.
The result of the compilation/linking is properly interpreted by Eclipse, which produces a list of errors that I can explore in GUI.

**Can I perform this with VSCode?**
I understand one can configure and then execute make build tasks via menu or a bound keyboard shortcut (I still have to check how to do this). But I am also specifically interested in the option of having some pull down menu with build tasks that I can double-click (which does not require scrolling across a long list of available unrelated commands).

This OP is closely related to [Quick navigation between a list of compilation errors and culprit code lines in Visual Studio Code with C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77399081/quick-navigation-between-a-list-of-compilation-errors-and-culprit-code-lines-in)

Comment: Just install the cmake plugin and don't worry about whether it's using make or not (i think it uses ninja by default if it's available)

Comment: [How to add a run button in visual studio code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66958884/2752075)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - Your suggestion seems to be spot on. It also seems to add one button for each task. Is there a way to group task buttons (or hide/show them selectively), so I can see only build tasks?

Comment: *"Is there a way to group task buttons"* Nope, don't know of any.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat task groups are a thing (`group` property (as shown in my answer)), but whether that extension you point to does anything with that info is its own business.

Answer (score 1):

I see this as an XY problem. The [`ms-vscode.makefile-tools`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.makefile-tools) contributes commands to build targets. Ex. when I create a simple CMake hello world and use the `Unix Makefiles` generator, I get a Makefile, and the Makefile Tools extension contributes the commands `Makefile: Build the target ALL` and `Makefile: Build the current target` (command ID `makefile.buildTarget`, which you can bind to a keyboard shortcut, and there's also `makefile.setBuildTarget` and `makefile.buildAll`, and a host of other commands which you can find listed in [its extension manifest](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-makefile-tools/blob/main/package.json)). Note that you may need to adjust the `makefile.makefilePath` setting in your workspace [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson).

But if you really want to write a build task yourself, nobody's stopping you. Ex.

```json
{
   "label": "starball's example makefile task",
   "type": "process",
   "command": "make",
   "args": ["all"],
   "options": {
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}", // can change to wherever your makefile is
      "env": {},
   },
   "group": {
      "kind": "build",
      "isDefault": "**/*.{cpp,cxx}" // adjust globbing as needed
   },
   "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"], // trigger suggestions to see other options. Ex. "$msvc".
}
```

You could probably smarten up the above task using [command variable substitution](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_command-variables). The Makefile Tools extension makes [some commands available for that](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-makefile-tools/blob/main/docs/makefile-settings.md).

Also, if you're using CMake to generate your Makefiles, you might as well just use the [`ms-vscode.cmake-tools`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools) VS Code extension, whose docs for building you can find [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/build.md).

Comment: I am a newbie with VSC, and I am not familiar with its notation.
I will check this answer.
In the meantime, as EDITed, do you know of any double-click method for building (which does not require scrolling across a long list of available unrelated commands)?